# Cant install Windows 8 OEM

Tags: windows, windows-8, oem

I have a **Dell 23" Windows 8 touch Inspiron** computer.

It came pre-loaded with *Windows 8* but was not activated.
I have an *OEM* product key and disc, and genuine sticker label.
When I try to enter the key into the pre-loaded Windows, it won't activate because it doesn't match the Windows that is installed.

The *Windows 8 Pro OEM* disc was sealed and unopened when I got the computer so when I tried to install it failed because Windows was already installed.

Does anyone know how I can set up my Windows 8 Pro OEM onto my Dell PC?

Comment: Did calling Dell not get you anywhere?

Comment: Im on the dell site now, Im running a full service tag/system diagnostic then ill call support. - thanks